# addEventListener conflicts with media

Tags: javascript, audio

I am trying to find a solution for this:
I have many  elements on a page and am implementing the following code which does what I need.

```
document.addEventListener(
  'play',
  function (evt) {
    if (document.$_currentlyPlaying) {
      document.$_currentlyPlaying.pause()
      document.$_currentlyPlaying.load()
    }
    document.$_currentlyPlaying = evt.target
  },
  true
)
```

The problem with this is that I have a looping video file in the page as well that is effected by this solution. So I need to target just the audio elements (or otherwise specified elements). I have tried using this on classes, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('class')
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].addEventListener(
    'play',
    function (evt) {
      if (x.$_currentlyPlaying) {
        x.$_currentlyPlaying.pause()
        x.$_currentlyPlaying.load()
      }
      x.$_currentlyPlaying = evt.target
    },
    true
  )
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or how to do what I want since I am not very familiar with JS and am trying to combine code I have found from searching for solutions.

Comment: For one thing you need to continue with the x[i] syntax al the way through your code, although probably you will have a problem with closure

Comment: *"... have many elements on a page and am implementing the following code which does what I need."* What does this code supposed to do? Is it supposed to pause any audio that plays? Is it supposed to pause an audio if another audio starts playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Mutually Exclusive Playback

> *"... have many elements on a page and am implementing the following code which does what I need."*

Assuming what is needed is mutually exclusive playback (for now on referred to as MEP). MEP is a shared behavior of a group of media players in which when one player begins playing it's media, the other players will either pause or stop playing.

---

### [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/fAMgHn7wCArPA65H0rHt/)

### Demo

**Details are commented in demo.**

**Note:** The audio may be inaudible, but you'll notice that only one `<audio>` tag will play while the other two pause and load. Go to this [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/fAMgHn7wCArPA65H0rHt/) for a fully functional demo.

```js
// Collect all <audio> tags into a NodeList
var clips = document.querySelectorAll('audio');

/* 
Loop through the NodeList and register each <audio>
to the playing event.
When triggered, callback function mep() is called.
*/
for (let i = 0; i < clips.length; i++) {
  clips[i].addEventListener('playing', mep);
}

function mep(e) {
  /* 
  e.target is the <audio> that started playing
  On each loop check if <audio> is NOT e.target
  and then pause and load it.
  */
  for (let i = 0; i < clips.length; i++) {
    if (clips[i] !== e.target) {
      clips[i].pause();
      clips[i].load();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
video, section {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
}
```

```html
<video src='https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005609.mp4' loop controls autoplay width='49%'></video>
<section>
  <audio src='https://od.lk/s/NzlfOTEyMzgyNF8/jerky.mp3' controls></audio>
  <audio src='https://od.lk/s/NzlfOTEwMzM5OV8/righteous.mp3' controls></audio>
  <audio src='https://od.lk/s/NzlfOTEyMzg0OV8/misty_forest.mp3' controls></audio>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution @zer00ne